# Escribir objetos en un fichero

Tags: java, eclipse, object

*Parece que me pide que añada aclaraciones. Esto no tiene nada que ver con el código, lo escribo para que me deje editar la publicación.*

Tengo un problema con **ficheros**.

Quiero *guardar objetos en un fichero*, y eso funciona. El fallo viene ahora: solo me **guarda el último objeto** que le paso y no estoy seguro que me lo guarde como objeto. **Este es el código**:

```
private String n_cuenta, nombre;

//relacionados con la id del usuario
private int titular, autorizado;
private float saldo;

public Cuenta(String n_cuenta, String nombre, int titular, int autorizado, float saldo){
    this.n_cuenta = n_cuenta;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.titular = titular;
    this.autorizado = autorizado;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}      


/**
         * Crea una cuenta y la guarda en un fichero.
         * @param c
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
         */
    public void crearCuenta(Cuenta c) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    boolean existe = comprobarExistencia(c);

    if(existe==true) System.err.println("Existe el objeto, amigo.");
    else {
        ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/media/sda1/unai11794/cuentas.dat",true));

        ostream.writeObject(c);
        ostream.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Comprueba que un objeto existe en el fichero cuentas.dat
 * @param c es la cuenta a buscar
 * @return
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
public boolean comprobarExistencia(Cuenta c) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    //EOF End Of File
    boolean EOF = false, existe = false;        
    ObjectInputStream istream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/media/sda1/unai11794/cuentas.dat")));

    //lee objetos mientras no se lance la excepcion de end of file.
    //en caso que se lance, EOF es true.
    while(!EOF){
        try{
            //se guarda el objeto del fichero en una instancia de Cuenta.
            Cuenta temporal = (Cuenta) istream.readObject();

            if(temporal.equals(c)){
                EOF = true;
                existe = true;
            }
        } catch(EOFException e){
            EOF = true;
        }
    }   

    istream.close();
    return existe;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cuenta a = new Cuenta("00001","Ahorros",113,0,500);
    Cuenta b = new Cuenta("00003","Viajes",58,2,3000);
    try {
        a.crearCuenta(a);
        b.crearCuenta(b);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que escribe en el fichero cuando intento guardar los dos objetos anteriores ***(a y b)***:

```
sr cajero.CuentaI
autorizadoFsaldoItitularLn_cuentatLjava/lang/String;Lnombreq~xpE;:t00003tViajes
```

Aparte si uso primero el método **comprobarExistencia()** y luego el de **crearCuenta()**, me salta esta excepción:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que falta para ver la definición completa de la clase `Cuenta`?

Comment: @PabloLozano solo me faltaba añadir el constructor. Ya está todo el código que hace falta.

Comment: No todo: ¿La clase cuenta implementa `Serializable`?

Comment: 1º cada clase tiene que implementar serializable con un codigo long en cada una como atributo, luego en el main tiene el serializa el deserializa y hay comprueba lo que haya en el fichero y lo que quieras

Comment: @carlosdiaz Sí, la clase Serializable es de java.io. Sirve para que se pueda usar ficheros y objetos.

Comment: No es un clase, es una interfaz que debes implementar en tu clase

Comment: exacto donde esta el titulo de la clase tiene que poner implements serializable en cada clase que tengas y en el main y ademas en los atributo de la clase debe de llevar private static final long serialVersionUID = 8799656478674716638L; (el numero cambia en cada clase le pud poner el que quieras